# How to echo month dynamically according to year

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have following code

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="row">
            <div  id="year" class="col-md-3 ">
                <select id="year1" class = "form-control" name="year" onblur="sctMonth()">
                   <option id="1" value="" disabled selected>-- Year --</option>';

    $year_query = "SELECT  DISTINCT YEAR (uploaddate) AS OrderYear FROM billTable  WHERE username='$log_username' ORDER BY uploaddate ASC ";
    $result_year_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $year_query);

    echo $e2= mysqli_error($db_conx );
    while ( $year_query = mysqli_fetch_row($result_year_query)){
        $year_query = $year_query[0];
        echo '<option value='.$year_query.'>'.$year_query.'</option>';
    }
    echo '      </select>
            </div>';

    echo '<div  id="month" class="col-md-3 ">
            <select id="month1" class = "form-control" name="month" >
               <option id="1" value="" disabled selected>-- Month --</option>';

    if(isset($_POST["monthcheck"])) {
        include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
        $year = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["monthcheck"]);//year options for month
        $month_query = "SELECT DISTINCT MONTHNAME(uploaddate) AS OrderMONTH 
                        FROM billTable 
                        WHERE username='$log_username' AND year(uploaddate) = '$year' 
                        ORDER BY uploaddate ASC ";
        $result_month_query= mysqli_query($db_conx, $month_query);
        while ( $month_query = mysqli_fetch_row($result_month_query)){
            $month_query = $month_query[0];
            //echo json_encode($month_query);
            echo '<option value='.$month_query.'>'.$month_query.'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '      </select>
            </div>
            <span id="month1_status"></span></div>';
            //echo $year ;
?>
```

What I am trying to do this when user selects year, month should be display accordingly using ajax, I send year to php using ajax but  I can't figure out how to display month and refresh as year changes ,currently it just shows blank select box, Or is it better to pass month as array using `json_encode($month_query);` , but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Please format the code, this is impossible to read. Additionally, where does your ajax call happen? in `db_conx.php` ?

Comment: If you select a year 'month has to display accordingly' with what? And please, as @user5310277 say re-format your code and post the ajax call.

Comment: below is  ajax call and is used to display files                                    function sctMonth(){
                var s = _("year1").value;
                if(s != ""){
                   
                    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_includes\catgorieQuery.php");
                    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                            _("month1").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
      }
     }
                    ajax.send("month1="+s);
    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but the code is quite unreadable. I recommend trying to write more readable because you'll thank yourself later.

I think is missing a piece of your code and explain better what is wrong with him

btw. here is a more readable version

```
<?php

$log_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $log_username);
$year_query = <<<SQL
  SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(uploaddate) AS OrderYear
    FROM billTable
  WHERE username = "{$log_username}"
  ORDER BY uploaddate ASC  
SQL;

$query_year_result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $year_query);
$query_year_error = mysqli_error($db_conx);

$select_block = <<<HTML
<div class="row">
  <div id="year" class="col-md-3">
    <select id="year1" class="form-controler" name="year" onblur="sctMonth()">
      <option id="1" value="" disabled selected>-- Year --</option>
      YEAR_OPTIONS
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="month" class="col-md-3">
    <select id="month1" class="form-controler" name="month">
      <option id="1" value="" disabled selected>-- Month --</option>
      MONTH_OPTIONS
    </select>
  </div>
  <span id="month1_status"></span></div>
</div>
HTML;

$year_options = "";

if (!$query_year_error) {
  while($row_year_query = mysqli_fetch_row($query_year_result)) {
    $year = $row_year_query[0];
    $year_options .= "<option value="{$year}"></option>";
  }
}

$month_options = "";

if (isset($_POST['monthcheck'])) {
  // I'll left this here commented because I dont know why are you calling here
  // if you use $qb_conx before  
  // include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");

  $year = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["monthcheck"]);
  $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $year);

  $month_query = <<<SQL
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTHNAME(uploaddate) AS OrderMONTH 
      FROM billTable 
    WHERE username = "{$log_username}" AND year(uploaddate) = "{$year}"
    ORDER BY uploaddate ASC 
  SQL;

  $query_month_result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $month_query);
  $query_month_error = mysqli_error($db_conx);  

  if (!$query_month_result) {
    while($row_month_query = mysqli_fetch_row($query_month_result)) {
      $month = $row_month_query[0];
      $month_options .= "<option value="{$month}">{$month}</option>";
    }
  }
}
$select_block = str_replace('YEAR_OPTIONS', $year_options, $select_block);
$select_block = str_replace('MONTH_OPTIONS', $month_options, $select_block);

echo $select_block;
```

Comment: Thnx for more clean code :)  I call monthcheck to display files using ajax                `function sctMonth(){
                var s = _("year1").value;
                if(s != ""){
                   
                    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_includes\catgorieQuery.php");
                    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                            _("month1").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
      }
     }
                    ajax.send("month1="+s);
    }
   }`

Comment: @user5310277 the php code is the code inside `php_includes\catgorieQuery.php` ?

Comment: yes the above php code is in php_includes\catgorieQuery.php , contains only this code and ajax is on another page.

Comment: But in this case the ajax call is wrong because of in the formatted php code the result of the code is not only options for select month1. in that case is better split the formatted php code in two pieces: one for years and another for months so you can reuse the month piece in years for the first call and then you can use the month piece from the ajax call